# two dimensional array combine in java

Tags: java, arrays

How can I combine two dimensional array like this in java?

here is 2-dimensional arrays

```
a b c d        i j k l
e f g h        m n o p
```

i want to get combine result like this

```
a b c d
e f g h
i j k l
m n o p
```

Comment: I tried to use ArrayUtils libray but ArrayUtils.addAll combine array beside, not below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Make an array the size of both arrays combined
2. Insert the first array into the final array
3. insert the second array into the final array, offset by the height of the first array

Your friends for this are for loops

This doesn't cover cases where the arrays aren't the same width, but you haven't explained what you want it to do anyway

Answer (score -1):

Try this (assuming you are using String type, array1 and array2 are the two arrays to be combined, and array is the combined array)

```
String[][] array = new String[array1.length + array2.length][];
System.arraycopy(array1, 0, array, 0, array.length);
System.arraycopy(array2, 0, array, array1.length, array2.length);
```